# Finding the real roots of a set of multivariate polynomial in an interval

Tags: polynomials, roots, nonlinear-optimization, multivariate-polynomial

**Problem:** I have a set of $m$ multivariate polynomials over $k$ variables, with an upper bound on the degrees $n$:

$$
\{f_i(x_1,x_2...x_k)\}_{i=1}^{m}
$$

My goal is to find if there's a real root such that for all $j$, $0 \leq x_j \leq 1$ i.e. the root is in the k-dimensional hypercube.

**What I know:** I know that this can be symbolically solved using Gröbner bases but the operation is too costly for my purposes since I need to do this multiple times. Right now I'm doing this numerically with the Newton-Raphson method but sometimes it converges to a root outside the hypercube even if one exists inside and I don't have an intuition for a heuristic starting point picking algorithm. I was able to find a [multidimensional generalization of the Bisection method](https://www.mm.bme.hu/%7Ebachrathy/research_EN.html) but I don't have the guarantee that the function will have differing signs at the vertices of the hypercube. I was wondering if there's something like a multidimensional/multivariate version of Sturm's theorem so I can solve the problem without explicitly finding the roots. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43979/counting-roots-multidimensional-sturms-theorem) question indicates that it is not possible but it is 13 years old and I don't have the intuition to evaluate the answers provided.

Thanks for your help.